# Sum rows with value larger than n into one in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, summarize

I have a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(count=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6), value=c(100,50,60,70,2,6,8))

  count value
1     0   100
2     1    50
3     2    60
4     3    70
5     4     2
6     5     6
7     6     8
```

How do I sum value larger than `"n"` into one row? So for example, if I choose `n = 3` then I want to have:

```
  count value
1     0   100
2     1    50
3     2    60
4     3    70
5    >3    16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a dplyr solution using `replace`. The downside is, it needs to be `arranged` if `>3` should be the last line (otherwise it'd be pretty concise).

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(count = replace(count, count > 3, ">3")) %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% 
  arrange(count == ">3")
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   count value
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 0       100
#> 2 1        50
#> 3 2        60
#> 4 3        70
#> 5 >3       16
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Coerce the count to factor with everything above `3` collapsed into `">3"`. Then `aggregate` the values by count.

```
df$count <- factor(ifelse(df$count > 3, ">3", df$count), levels = c(1:3, ">3"))
aggregate(value ~ count, df, sum)
#  count value
#1     0   100
#2     1    50
#3     2    60
#4     3    70
#5    >3    16
```

---

### R 4.1.0 or above.

Starting with R 4.1.0, there are a new pipe operator and a new lambda, that can be used if the column `count` is to be kept as is, meaning, if the transformation is temporary only.

```
df |>
  within(count <- factor(ifelse(count > 3, ">3", count), levels = c(1:3, ">3"))) |>
  (\(x)aggregate(value ~ count, x, sum))()
#  count value
#1     0   100
#2     1    50
#3     2    60
#4     3    70
#5    >3    16
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
    group_by(count = case_when(count >3 ~ '>3', 
     TRUE ~ as.character(count))) %>% 
    summarise(value = sum(value), .groups = 'drop')
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R option using `aggregate`

```
transform(
  aggregate(
    . ~ count,
    transform(df, count = replace(count, count > 3, Inf)),
    sum
  ),
  count = replace(count, is.infinite(count), ">3")
)
```

gives

```
  count value
1     0   100
2     1    50
3     2    60
4     3    70
5    >3    16
```